# Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'ExecuteScalar' accepts this number of arguments

Tags: vb.net

Im pretty new to VB.NET and was wondering how I'd fix this error im getting.

**CODE**

```
 Dim sql As String = "SELECT (USER) FROM USER_CONSTANT"
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(strConn)
    Dim objDR As SqlDataReader
    Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    conn.Open()
    objDR = Cmd.ExecuteScalar(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    While objDR.Read()
        Label7.Text = objDR("USER")
```

Comment: the message means what it says - there is no CommandBehavior arg or any arg allowed for `ExecuteScalar`  you may have it confused (or pasted from) an `ExecuteReader()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ExecuteScalar method doesn't expect any parameter. The CommandBehavior enum could be passed to the ExecuteReader method, so I suppose that your code should be written as

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT (USER) FROM USER_CONSTANT"
Using conn = New SqlConnection(strConn)
Using Cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    conn.Open()

    Using objDR = Cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
       While objDR.Read()
          Label7.Text = objDR("USER")
       End While
    End Using
 End Using
 End Using
```

It is not clear if you expect to receive more than one record from this code. In case of multiple records returned then note that at every loop you change the content of the Label7.Text with the current USER and your loop ends with the last name displayed

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteScalar` does not accept any variables (see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx)). just change the line to `objDR = Cmd.ExecuteScalar`.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error says, there's no overload of `ExecuteScalar` which accepts that number of arguments.  [Or any arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand_methods.aspx).  Instead:

```
objDR = Cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

Or did you mean to use `ExecuteReader`, since you're intending to loop over the results and a scalar isn't a result set?

```
objDR = Cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
```